# Data table initialize after table body replace (ajax)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatable

I have a datatable it have a search box (date range filter) once i click the search button table body replace according to the filter(ajax).

my problem is i cant initialize table after ajax success.

**HTML**

```
<table data-page-length="20" id="occupancy" class="ui small celled table segment display" cellspacing="0"
       width="100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Arrivals</th>
        <th>Departures</th>
        <th>Occupied</th>
        <th>Available</th>
        <th>Occupancy</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="occupancyBody">

    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Ajax**

```
        type: 'POST',
        url: "../system/user/modules/" + MODULE_NAME + "/controller.php",
        data: "action=filterOc&" + url_data,
        success: function (resultData) {
            $('#occupancyBody').html(resultData);
            $('#occupancy').dataTable();
        }
    });
```

[sample screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvu31.png)

Answer (score 3):

You can use below mentioned code to reinitialize table after ajax call.

While defining datatable, you can store in a variable.

```
var myTable =  $('#occupancy').DataTable({ // all your configuration });
```

Now after ajax call you can call below line.

```
myTable.ajax.reload();
```

**also remove this line in ajax:success function.**

```
$('#occupancy').dataTable();
```

Let me know if it not works.

Comment: my code is like this

var dt= $('#occupancy').dataTable();

$('#occupancyBody').html(resultData);
            dt.ajax.reload();

Comment: Can you please check my new answer and make according changes

Comment: This instance of Datatable doesn't have ajax source data (i.e.: there's no ajax option), that's why ajax.reload() throws an error

Answer (score 0):

Please check here

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var table = $('#occupancy').dataTable();
  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "../system/user/modules/controller.php",
      data: "action=filterOc&",
      success: function (resultData) {
         $('#occupancyBody').html(resultData);
         table.ajax.reload();
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.15/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table data-page-length="20" id="occupancy" class="ui small celled table segment display" cellspacing="0"
       width="100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Arrivals</th>
        <th>Departures</th>
        <th>Occupied</th>
        <th>Available</th>
        <th>Occupancy</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="occupancyBody">

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: its working perfect but my problem is by default added  some filters. please check the screen shot. "No matching record found"

Answer (score 0):

The `ajax.reload()` API function should only work if you included the `ajax` option in Datatable's initialization (see [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax)).

In this case, I'd recommend to add `destroy:true` to the initialization of Datatables, something like this:

```
$('#occupancy').DataTable({ destroy:true})
```

This would allow you to re-create the table every time the ajax call is successful.

Answer (score -1):

hi i guess you selected wrong body id :

```
$('#occupancyBody').html(resultData);
```

but in your html :

```
 <tbody id="dailyAct">
```

hope it's help,

Comment: its a typing mistake. please check it again